# Installation of freya alongside Mac OS using DVD stalls

Tags: release-freya

I'm trying to load elementary Freya to run alongside my Mac OS on two of my laptop Mac computers.

My two computers are :

1. MacBook (13-inch Late 2007) - Intel Core 2 Duo
2. MacBook Pro (15-inch Mid 2009) - Intel Core 2 Duo

I'm using your installation page - https://elementary.io/docs/installation#download-elementary-os

and following the instruction for Mac OS.

Both my computers are Intel Core 2 Duo and therefore I understand that a bootable USB stick for Freya will not work. So, I have followed the route of downloading your iso for Freya and burning it to DVD.

I am successful in loading Freya to my older MacBook running Freya alongside the Mac OS section of the HD.

However, I am not able to load Freya to my younger MacBook Pro. In booting from the DVD, as mentioned above, I get the following message showing up against a black screen :

controller found
[ 2.028751 ] ACPI PCC probe failed
[ 2.247927 ] nouveau E[ PDISP ] [ 0000:02:00.0 ] 01:0006:0242: no bios dp data

and I'm left with a blinking hyphen and there seems no way forward.  I have to force shutdown on the computer to come out of this position.

Can anyone help me please ?

Alastair

Answer (score 1):

I have a Macbook 2006 and it only boots 32 bit version of any Ubuntu distro.

You might need to boot in '**nomodeset**' or '**noapic**'.

Follow this instructions, it might work.

**https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/7163/5726**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but it sounds like it might be an error on the installation disk?

Anyway, you actually can install freya 0.3.2 on your MacBooks using a bootable USB stick. I did this on a MacBook 4.1 (13-inch early 2008 Intel Core 2 Duo), and it worked perfectly well. There shouldn't be any reason why this wouldn't work on your computer. That way you can also try a new download of the disk image, maybe yours got corrupted causing the error message.