# Problem installing elementary os freya

Tags: release-freya

I am a total newbie to Linux as I've never used Linux before. But however I wanted to dual boot windows 10 with elementary is 0.3.2 Freya.
What I did was create a bootable USB with Rufus and when I booted up the installer, and went to try elementary is it shows the following message :

[0.029189] Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0 (expected1)

[1.180440] ACPI PCC probe failed.

[1.224485] mmc0: Unknown controller version (3). You may experience problems.

Along with this, it showed the "e" logo twice like in split screen and when it disappeared it froze until I had to force restart my laptop.

Next when I tried to installed elementary os, it showed the same errors but this time it displayed the setup in split screen  as shown in the attached pic.
Now I don't know what the real problem is so pls help.
[image]
PS- Sry abt the bad pic quality.

Comment: What type of computer are you using? Information on the brand, model, and configuration would be super helpful here. Thanks!

Comment: @RyanDeBeasi Clevo Barebone - P750DM
CPU - Intel Skylake Desktop Grade i5-6500
GPU - NVIDIA GTX 970M 6GB GDDR5
RAM1 - G.Skill Ripjaws 8GB 2133MHz DDR4
RAM2 - G.Skill Ripjaws 8GB 2133MHz DDR4
Storage1 - SATA 2.5” 1TB 7200rpm HDD
Storage2 - M.2 2280 120GB NVMe PCIe SSD

Answer (score 1):

Try booting in '**nomodeset**'

Boot the live cd and when you see this screen hit **Tab** in your keyboard

[image]

Then press F6 and select **nomodeset**, hit **Enter** and then **Esc**. Now try Installing eOS.

[image]

Comment: The tab button didn't do anything and that screen too didn't show up.

Comment: Some background on this suggestion: Your NVIDIA graphics card might be the culprit - Linux drivers for these cards can be finnicky. When you boot from the live CD, do you get the second screen, where you can "Try elementary OS without installing" or "Install elementary OS"? If not, what happens? More background here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/695764/display-distortion-on-newer-kernels-drivers

Comment: Yes i got the 2nd screen (grub menu) which asks directly to try/install elementary os but at higher resolution with the options at the top left corner and without the "elementary" logo.

Comment: Okay, this is the first menu that pops up on my screen -> [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-pG-99KohfRSkk3eW9CZ1JvY0k).

Comment: pressed f6 when selected install elementary os and then this happened [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-pG-99KohfRQmM1Y0g1ZGRSbGM) [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-pG-99KohfRYkpIN292YVBIY2M) [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-pG-99KohfRZ3JaWmRmNW1ybms)

Comment: Are you using more than one monitor? (Sorry if you said somewhere else, I didn't see it). Or does the screen look like that one just one screen?? That is weird...something I haven't seen before.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the USB with a different program. I have had issues with Rufus in the past. This one always works for me: http://www.linuxliveusb.com/ and I've used it to install elementary at least 10 times. (Not affiliated with that program in any way, just know it works).

There have also been issues with Freya and the Skylake processors. Search on here for "Skylake" for more on that!

Good luck!!! It really is an awesome OS and worth the effort to get it installed.

Comment: i am currently using rufus to create the bootable usb.

Comment: I know you are. Try something else. I would put my money on the fact that Freya doesn't support Skylake without running kernal 4.4 though...

Comment: Nope. Still isnt working. Btw can you explain running kernal 4.4

Comment: Hmmm. You tried Live Linux USB Creator in Windows 10? Was it the same error message? Does it boot to the installer at all? I'm not sure yiu can upgrade the kernel without installing first. OR if you can, I don't know how.

Comment: It just goes to the grub menu and after selecting install elementary os the same above error shows up. I've added the links to the pictures for what shows up on Giovanni's reply.

Comment: Try posting on the Google+ page. There are a lot of people on there that are smarter than me. It's hard for me to see exactly what's going on in those pictures. https://plus.google.com/communities/104613975513761463450 Sorry man, I would really love to help you get this to work because it is awesome, but I've reached the limit of my knowledge.